# Spotify API authorisation via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spotify

I am using the following code to make requests to the Spotify API via Google Apps Script:

```
function search() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var artist = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  artist = encodeURIComponent(artist.trim());
  var result = searchSpotify(artist);
  Logger.log(result);
}

function searchSpotify(artist) {
  //searches spotify and returns artist ID
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + artist + "&type=artist&limit=1", 
  { method: "GET",
    headers:{
      "contentType": "application/json",
      'Authorization': "Bearer BQBnpSUdaEweirImw23yh2DH8OGhTwh5a_VnY_fgb2BPML0KvFvYd04CaEdUhQN9N4ZUXMIVfJ1MjFe1_j0Gl0UoHDhcoC_dklluZyOkq8Bo6i2_wfxSbGzP3k5EUjUKuULAnmTwCdkdZQnl-SNU0Co"
            },
  });
  json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var uri = data.artists.items[0].uri.slice(15);
  var getArtists = getRelatedArtists(uri);
  Logger.log(getArtists);
  return getArtists;
}

function getRelatedArtists(uri) {
  //searches related artists with the returned ID
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/" + uri + "/related-artists", 
  { method: "GET",
    headers:{
      "contentType": "application/json",
      'Authorization': "Bearer BQBnpSUdaEweirImw23yh2DH8OGhTwh5a_VnY_fgb2BPML0KvFvYd04CaEdUhQN9N4ZUXMIVfJ1MjFe1_j0Gl0UoHDhcoC_dklluZyOkq8Bo6i2_wfxSbGzP3k5EUjUKuULAnmTwCdkdZQnl-SNU0Co"
            },
  });
  json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var listArtists = [];
  for(var i = 0, len = data.artists.length; i < len; i++){
    listArtists.push(data.artists[i].name);
                 }
  return listArtists;
}
```

This works fine using the temporary Authorisation token from the Spotify website but this token refreshes every hour and so is obviously useless.

I am trying to use my own Authorisation token and ID which I have setup on Spotify however I'm struggling to make this work. As I understand it I may need to add an extra step at the beginning to start the authorisation process but I've tried all methods suggested but keep receiving server errors.

Comment: I think that providing the specification document of API will be help users think of about your issue.

Comment: Sorry, the full documentation is quite lengthy so I have linked it in here. It describes several Authorisation flow options: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorizaton-code-flow

Comment: I should also add that it is the Client Credentials flow at the bottom that I am trying to use.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You already have both client_id and client_secret. And you want to retrieve the access token using "Client Credentials Flow". You want to know the Google Apps Script for "Client Credentials Flow". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That is correct. Whenever I attempt to connect I receive an error saying the grant_type parameter is not valid.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer including a sample script. Could you please confirm it? I cannot test this script. So if this didn't work, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the detail information? By the way, about ``Whenever I attempt to connect I receive an error saying the grant_type parameter is not valid.``, if you have a script, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the document, it seems that "Client Credentials Flow" uses the basic authorization.

**In order to use this, at first, you are required to retrieve "client_id" and "client_secret".**

#### Sample script:

```
var clientId = "### client id ###"; // Please set here.
var clientSecret = "### client secret ###"; // Please set here.

var url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
var params = {
  method: "post",
  headers: {"Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(clientId + ":" + clientSecret)},
  payload: {grant_type: "client_credentials"},
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
Logger.log(res.getContentText())
```

- From curl sample, `grant_type` is required to send as form.

#### Result:

The document says that the response is as follows.

```
{
   "access_token": "NgCXRKc...MzYjw",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "expires_in": 3600,
}
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your situation.
- I prepared this sample script by the sample curl in the document.

#### Reference:

- [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow)

### Edit:

As your next issue, you want to retrieve the access token from the returned value. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please modify my script as follows.

#### From:

```
Logger.log(res.getContentText())
```

#### To:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
Logger.log(obj.access_token)
```

- When the value is returned from API, it returns as a string. So it is required to parse it as an object using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: ah! I wasn't using the Utilities.base64Encode correctly. Just one thing, probably really simple, but it returns the following object...{"access_token":" I've hidden this out for now ","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"scope":""}. I'm struggling to add the contents of the access token into a variable and wondering if it's because the object key is in quotations. Variable is returning as undefined.

Comment: @herman Thank you for replying. From your reply, it was found that the script worked fine. But I apologize for my incomplete answer. I added a modification point. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @herman Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Yes your solution worked perfectly here. Thank you once again.